# tokio-tungstenite with tokio::select! macro?

Tags: rust, websocket, rust-tokio, rust-futures

The documentation for the [tokio-tungstenite](https://crates.io/crates/tokio-tungstenite) crate mostly just directs you to the [examples](https://github.com/snapview/tokio-tungstenite/tree/master/examples) section.

The [client example](https://github.com/snapview/tokio-tungstenite/blob/master/examples/client.rs) hasn't been updated in a few years and I saw some unfamiliar async code here and because Rust's async APIs are still in flux I wanted to check the use `futures_util::future::select` was still idiomatic in this situation.

In particular, it *seems* to work fine if I replace it with the more commonly seen `tokio::select!` macro, which doesn't require pinning the passed futures.

I have good familiarity with tokio's APIs but not so much the lower level `futures` ones. Is there a reason to manually pin here and use the `future::select` instead? More generally, in modern idiomatic async Rust code when would one use the latter?

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine to replace any use of `futures::future::select()` with `tokio::select!` (or [`futures::select!`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/macro.select.html)). They both do the same thing. `select!` allow for more than one future, while `select()` gives you a named future. I prefer `select!` when I can (I think it is also more performant, but I'm not sure).